# Find deleted row from Merge Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

Merge Replication creates a table named **MSmerge_tombstone**, it records all deleted rows. My question is, how can i find this deleted row? This row's Data is recorded in any table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To track changes, Merge Replication must be able to uniquely identify every row in every published table.  To accomplish this Merge Replication adds a **rowguid** column to every published table.

[MSmerge_tombstone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186771.aspx) contains a column **rowguid**.  The rowguid in MSmerge_tombstone is the rowguid of the row that has been deleted.  If a row has been deleted, the actual row data is NOT recorded by Merge Replication.  The best way to find the row data would be to grab the rowguid from MSmerge_tombstone and locate the row in a database backup.

Hopefully you have been taking and keeping backups.

Comment: I'm still doing some tests in my database whit replication, I have a backup but I'm not using it for now. I had this doubt after read that MSmerge_tombstone record deleted rows.
Thank you